# how to pass the strMessage (from codebehind to the script) to get the alert message

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

how to pass the strMessage (from codebehind to  the script) to get the alert message

i.e
if my strmessage from code behind is hi,

then i need

You Have Used already the message : hi

My code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var strFileName;

    function alertShowMessage() {
    alert("You Have Used already the message :"+ <%=strFileName %>+ ");
    }
</script>


datatable dtChkFile =new datatable();
dtChkFile = objutility.GetData("ChkFileName_SMSSent", new object[] {"rahul"}).Tables[0];
         if (dtChkFile.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < dtChkFile.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                  strMessage= dtChkFile.Rows[i]["Message"].To);

             }
         }
```

Comment: @Ranjana: I wonder what's the mindset behind posting questions that lack any sensible formatting. There's a formatting help on the side, there is a WYSIWYG preview window, and the other questions here on SO don't look like formatting would not work. So... you are not an *entirely* new user anymore. Time to get your question formatting right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on at what point you want the alert message to appear, consider using [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) / [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx). Here's a sample (also using the [AntiXSS library](http://antixss.codeplex.com) to javascript-encode the word to mitigate against quotes or any kind of XSS attack).

```
using Microsoft.Security.Application;

namespace RegisterClientScriptBlock
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String alertScript;
            String inputWord;
            String encodedWord;

            encodedWord = AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(inputWord);

            alertScript = "function alertShowMessage() {";

            if (checkIfWordHasBeenUsed(inputWord) == true)
            {
                alertScript = alertScript + "alert('You have already used the message:" + encodedWord + "');}";
            }
            else
            {
                alertScript = alertScript + "alert('You have not used the message:" + encodedWord + "');}";
            }

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alertShowMessage", alertScript, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you could define a variable that will contain the message text:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string SomeMessage = "Hello World";
}
```

And in the markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertShowMessage() {
    alert('You Have Used already the message : <%= SomeMessage %>');
}
</script>
```

You should also be aware that when you use `<%= SomeMessage %>`, the message won't be encoded and if it contains some special characters such as `'` it might break the javascript. [This blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/114530.aspx) contains a sample function that encodes strings used in javascript.

Comment: but it is not giving me the message to display in alert box

Answer (score 0):

Build your message with string builder or whatever method you prefer, and pass it to the following void

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Name: SendMessageToClient
//Abstract: Send a message to the client side.
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
protected void SendMessageToClient(string strMessage)
{
string strMessageToClient = "";

//Allow single quotes on client-side in JavaScript
strMessage = strMessage.Replace("'", "\\'");

strMessageToClient = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">alert( '" + strMessage + "' );</script>";

this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ErrorMessage", strMessageToClient);

}
```